# InvalidOperation: Invalid literal for Decimal: u' '

Tags: django

When the users perform allocation of money in each envelope sometimes they forgot to put amounts in other envelopes which result to '0'. Then it will result to InvalidOperation.

How to fix this error? Or How can the system get only the amount that is more than 0?

Exception

```
Types:  InvalidOperation

Value:  Invalid literal for Decimal: u''
```

envelopes/views.py in allocate (application)

```
            t2_payee = 'Envelope Transfer'



        for val in request.POST:

            if val[0:4] == "env_":

                env = Envelope.objects.get(pk=int(val[4:]))

                amt = Decimal(request.POST[val])


 <WSGIRequest
 path:/envelopes/allocate/6313/,
 GET:<QueryDict: {}>,
 POST:<QueryDict: {u'allocation_date': [u'2013-03-03'], u'month': [u'03'], 
      u'source': [u'6313'], u'year': [u'2013'], u'env_6316': [u''], 
      u'csrfmiddlewaretoken': [u'3kKoVymvIpbyhCknE1c3WH6YFznTaEoj'], 
      u'env_6315': [u'1'], u'env_6314': [u'0']}>,
 COOKIES:{'__utma': '136509540.132217190.1357543480.1362303551.1362307904.34',
```

'__utmb': '1

Comment: Post the relevant code and error trace. We don't know the context of the error in your application so "When the users perform allocation of money in each envelope sometimes" means nothing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your example value of env_6316 is empty, Decimal doesn't know how to convert that to a number. You should check if the val is empty and if so then replace it with 0 before converting to Decimal.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error while running a SQL query and attempting to construct a Pandas dataframe with the data returned from the query. An alteration to the query solved the problem for me. I had also attempted to CAST the column values returned, but ultimately, appending ::FLOAT8 to the problematic field was the only solution for me.

Example query:

```
SELECT sum(dollars)::FLOAT8 FROM [table] WHERE ...
```

sum(dollars) was the field causing the issue for me. It's Type in my table was numeric(10,6), and Size was 8.